# Mysql Query - That Is Returning Blatanty Incorrect Result

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

I am building a VPS node that is running Ubuntu 10.10LTS, Apache2, Mysql 5.1 and php5.

I could not log in to my website admin through the browser, even though I am using the correct login details. So I logged in from the command line to check the results.

When I run this query I get expected results:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
| id | username | email                 | password |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
|  1 | myUserName    | myUserName@mysite.com | myPassword |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
```

And the same goes for this query:

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1;
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
| id | username | email                 | password |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
|  1 | myUserName    | myUserName@mysite.com | myPassword |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I run this query I get this 'unexpected response':

```
mysql> select * from users where username = 'myUserName' and password = 'myPassword';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not sure why this is happening.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
BTW.. I will be encrypting the user details but for now I just want to get it set up.

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: Don't you have whitespaces after 'myUserName' ?

Comment: @CloudWeavers might be onto something; try using `username LIKE '%myUserName%'` to verify?

Comment: @Andrew -- yh that query worked

Comment: @Andrew --still not sure how to get the original query to work though

Comment: The issue is because, like @CloudWeavers mentioned, there's probably spaces in your username.  That is, you think its `myUserName` when in fact its `myUsername__`, where `_` are spaces.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick.  Ubuntu `10.10` is not an LTS release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to turn it into an answer, based on the formatting of your SQL queries, it looks like you have spaces in the field for your username.  That is:

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1;
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
| id | username | email                 | password |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
|  1 | myUserName    | myUserName@mysite.com | myPassword |
+----+----------+-----------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, the username field for `id=1` is `myUserName___`, where the `_` are used to illustrate spaces.  That's why, when you use `username LIKE 'myUserName%'` (which says include everything that begins with `myUserName`) works correctly.

Comment: Arrgh, thanks.  I spot the error now, a space after my username on my db_setup script. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help; these kind of things can be extremely frustrating to spot at times!

Comment: Arrrggg. I should have pushed that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Password is also the name of a mysql function that hashes passwords; I wonder if this could be the problem?  Try quoting the table names.

Additionally, there appears to be some whitespace after the string myUserName.  I suspect this indicates an application error.  If you were to `update users set username='myUserName' where id=1;` you would likely find it works.

Comment: Thx,  tried double and single quotes, plus these style quotes(not sure what there called): ``, also tried renaming the tables.  The same query works fine on the dev box.  Not sure what to do..;.